# Facebook like button opens popup window instead of edge.create event

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I am using facebook api to like a page, I am following this process
1) Click to Login to facebook
2) Click Like Button after login

Now the problem is, after login first time, when i click on the like button, it a popup window, instead of firing the `edge.create` event. But works correctly when i unlike and re like the page, Or reload the page.

This is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: well, it would help to include a test link, or a screenshot of that popup window, or both. please be more specific.

Comment: ok http://www.photopages.in/ this is the link

Comment: please provide the direct link to the like button

Comment: Actually the like button will be displayed after signing in to the facebook, the step displaying the like button is hidden

Comment: btw, it looks like you are trying to do something that is not allowed. incentivizing likes is not allowed, as you can read in the platform policy. you are not allowed to reward users for liking, or use like gating in any way.

Comment: Ok, thanks for guiding, i may ommit the 2nd step

Comment: you MUST omit that 2nd step. i just tried it btw, and it works for me. but you are immediately hiding the like button, which is also a no go. people always have to be able to unlike. but again, what you are trying to do is not allowed. you can't make liking a requirement for anything. people need to like something because they really want to.

Comment: @luschn Where in the facebook guidelines does it say that you can't hide the like button after they're done?

Comment: i said it´s a no go, i did not say it´s not allowed. incentivizing likes is not allowed, you cannot reward users for liking or hide content behind a like.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ - 4.5. - but you have to read the whole platform policy if you want to work with facebook stuff.